# Array of objects transformation in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
    let arr = [{start: 1, end: 5, group: [1, 3, 5]},
    {start: 12, end: 17, group: [6, 20,]}]
```

I need to transform this array into :

```
    let arr_transformed = [{start: 1, end: 5, group: 1},
    {start: 1, end: 5, group: 3},
    {start: 1, end: 5, group: 5},
    {start: 12, end: 17, group: 6},
    {start: 12, end: 17, group: 20}
    ]
```

Basically I need to copy objects values(start, end) with number of elements in group object and put single group number to it.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I knew that already there are plenty of answer are there. even though I am providing answer in another and simple way but not be best one.

```js
transformObject =(data)=>{
let cnt=0;
  let finalArray=[];

  for(let i=0;i <data.length;i++){
    let grouplen =data[i].group;
    for (let j = 0; j < grouplen.length; j++) {
      finalArray[cnt]={
        start: data[i].start,
        end: data[i].end,
        group: grouplen[j]
      }
      cnt++;
    }
  }
  return finalArray;
}
  let data = [{start: 1, end: 5, group: [1, 3, 5]},
  {start: 12, end: 17, group: [6, 20,]}];
  const result = transformObject(data);
  console.log("transformed Object:",result);
```

Answer (score 1):

So many ways…

Here's a one-liner that reduces on each element and maps the groups into the accumulator array:

```js
let arr = [{start: 1, end: 5, group: [1, 3, 5]},{start: 12, end: 17, group: [6, 20,]}]

let r = arr.reduce((a, {start, end, group}) => a.concat(group.map(group => ({start, end, group}))), [])
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `Array#reduce` with `Array#forEach`.

The idea is to loop over the source array, and then in each iteration, loop over the `group` key. In each inner iteration, you push the composed object to final result.

```js
let arr = [{start:1,end:5,group:[1,3,5]},{start:12,end:17,group:[6,20]}];

const transformed = arr.reduce((res, { start, end, group }) => {
  group.forEach(g => res.push({ start, end, group: g }));
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic pseudocode algorithm:

```
result = []
for object in arr {
    for group in object.group {
        result.push({object.start, object.end, group})
    }
}
return result
```

Iterate over array in outer loop, and over the groups within the inner loop, push  flattened objects into result array object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [{start: 1, end: 5, group: [1, 3, 5]},
{start: 12, end: 17, group: [6, 20,]}]
var arr_transformed = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var help = arr[i]['group'];
  delete arr[i]['group'];
  for(var j = 0; j < help.length; j++) {
    arr[i].group = help[j];
    arr_transformed.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
console.log(arr_transformed);
```

run this code and make your out put

Answer (score 0):

using forEach and map

```
let results = [];

arr.forEach( i => {
  results = results.concat(i.group.map(group => {
    return {
      start: i.start,
      end: i.end,
      group
    };
  }))
});
```